# How to package python code to be used on another computer by clicking an icon?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I know that sounds really basic. But I've been writing a program for us to use at my job, and I've been looking online every where trying to find out exactly how to package it and everything so I can just install it on my computer at work, click an icon and use it.

I just keep seeing so many different things online and can't quite figure out exactly what I'm doing.

Also, Ive been building this on `OS X` but at work we'll be using `windows`. 
But I would also like to package it for `OS X`.

I know this is probably entry level stuff, but I'm just getting overwhelmed with everything I'm finding on google.

Also, I don't know if this matters as far as the process goes, but I used `tkinter` for the `GUI`, and `sqlite3` for the `database`

Comment: you mean pyinstaller?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Pyinstaller` (see link below) to compile you script in an `exe` file that you can run on Windows (don't know for Mac though).

https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/